# Парсинг самописного языка разметки, PHP

Tags: php

Формат файла

```xml
<first>Items name</first>
<second>
    Item:one more
    Item:one more
</second>
```

Код который есть:

```php
if(($result = file_get_contents(FILENAME)) === false) die('failed to open or read file');
$result = explode("\n", $result);
foreach ($result as $string) {
    // ?
}
```

Вместо комментария хотелось бы сначала вытащить значение между `<first>`.
*Sscanf* прочтёт только *Items*, если делать маску `<first>%s</first>`.

Как ещё можно вытащить это значение?

Comment: А чем этот самописный язык отличается от XML, HTML, или чего-то другого подобного?

Comment: Разделители для строк между тэгами second. Не очень ясные требования к нему, поэтому необходимая гибкость.

Comment: парсите его как xml. получите   и first и second. А еще лучше сделайте   `<Item>one more</Item><Item>one more</Item>`

Comment: Э... Что значит "разделители между тегами"? Между открывающим и закрывающим тегом обычно находятся другие теги, или данные, или ничего (то бишь пробелы/табуляции/cr/lf и т.д.).  Пока никаких отличий от стандартных ML не вижу, как и повода изобретать свой парсер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе необходимо почитать про пасинг XML на php http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php .

```
if ($content = file_get_contents(FILENAME)) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
    $first = $xml->first;
    echo($first);
}
```

Кроме SimpleXMLElement - есть более продвинутые решения, например: DOMDocument (встроено в PHP), simplehtmldom - был очень хорош и похож на jQuery , но давно не обновлялся.

Answer (score 1):

Надо всего лишь дооформить этот недо-XML, и после этого можно работать стандартными средствами

```
$velosiped = "<first>Items name</first>
 <second>
   Item:one more
   Item:one more
 </second>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<start>$velosiped</start>");
echo $xml->first;
```